# What happens when a database connection object is not closed?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have a script which execute SQL queries every minute to insert data. Since it is executed every minute, I keep a global connection and cursor object and reuse them every time, unless an exception occurs. If an exception occurs, I reinitialise the connection and cursor again.

I understand that this is very bad practice. I want to know what happens when the same cursor is reused without closing it. Will it take data from an old query? I am using autocommit in pyodbc.

Comment: It will hold that connection in idle between script iterations (which may result in connection limit exceeding if script is scaled up)

Comment: Doesn't sound like it should be a problem. What's bad is creating new connections without disposing the old ones

Comment: I am using a single connection object I am not opening new, will it cause limit to exceed

Comment: How will limit exceed when it’s just one connection? But in production, if there are millions of users, you can have hundreds of thousands of simultaneous connections to the database. After using one connection, if you cannot transfer it to another user to make use of, then close it.

Comment: Yes, I agree it should be closed, but I just to understand if i reuse the same cursor again and again without closing, will it cause problem, like output of previous query